# How to fix error with removing all instances in a string c++

Tags: c++, string, loops, replace, error-handling

I am having a problem with removing all instances of "amp;" in a string in c++, I have created a loop to replace "amp;" with "" until there are no "amp;" instances left. I am having an unknown error where the program starts printing random characters, I have never seen it before. There is an image below. I have used mutliple other loops to remove things in the same program, so I am unsure why it is happening now.

Character Glitch: https://screenrec.com/share/EcVLHoasvU

This is the loop I have used:

```
try {
  while(DownloadLink.find("amp;") != string::npos){
    DownloadLink.replace(DownloadLink.find("amp;"), 4, "");
  }
} catch (const exception& Error) {
  cerr << "Error: " << Error.what();
}
```

For a minimal reproducible example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string DownloadLink;
    
    DownloadLink = "https://rr2---sn-gjo-w43l.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1685464604&amp;ei=vNF1ZPypCYLk8wS04YS4Bw&amp;ip=193.135.13.240&amp;id=o-AOroxIeyjf0SXpp4Jjav3mMxHNrQnAmWFHliIzDxKFK8&amp;itag=22&amp;source=youtube&amp;requiressl=yes&amp;mh=xJ&amp;mm=31%2C29&amp;mn=sn-gjo-w43l%2Csn-ab5sznly&amp;ms=au%2Crdu&amp;mv=m&amp;mvi=2&amp;pl=24&amp;initcwndbps=248750&amp;spc=qEK7B7YCjgMFmSN1lRYNJdgmcwOfjSE&amp;vprv=1&amp;svpuc=1&amp;mime=video%2Fmp4&amp;ratebypass=yes&amp;dur=1535.256&amp;lmt=1685416420579114&amp;mt=1685442532&amp;fvip=1&amp;fexp=24007246%2C24362688%2C51000022&amp;beids=24350017&amp;c=ANDROID&amp;txp=4318224&amp;sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cspc%2Cvprv%2Csvpuc%2Cmime%2Cratebypass%2Cdur%2Clmt&amp;sig=AOq0QJ8wRAIgOFevBFo84_aL0L8hSD1vwztRDGStTF6OaohO4gA8OIUCIE1wN5685dZ7FROQXO9W7BOv4thF8B3KxFE6iefy60xS&amp;lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&amp;lsig=AG3C_xAwRgIhAOO9mtQzsKDrCes2EPmTwOyB8QtGblPFo30I9VrOsSnMAiEAh91ImIfeaugrIfJ4Q0U30viktdo4sWHv0ywQV0kfjt8%3D&amp;title=Ages+1+-+100+Fight+For+$500,000";
    while(DownloadLink.find("amp;") != string::npos){
        DownloadLink.replace(DownloadLink.find("amp;"), 4, "");
    }
    cout << DownloadLink;

    return 0;
}
```

Has anyone seen anything like this before or knows how to help?
Thanks

Comment: This doesn't print any characters unless there's an exception so what exception do you get? What type Is `DownloadLink`? Please show a [mre].

Comment: @TedLyngmo There is no exception caught, it always shows the error with the random characters. The type of DownloadLink is a string, and the current content of it is, "https://rr2---sn-gjo-w43l.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1685464604&ei=vNF1ZPypCYLk8wS04YS4Bw&ip=193.135.13.240&id=o-AOroxIeyjf0SXpp4Jjav3mMxHNrQnAmWFHliIzDxKFK8&itag=22&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=xJ&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-gjo-w43l%2Csn-ab5sznly&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=2&pl=24"...

Comment: Then, please show a [mre].

Comment: @TedLyngmo I have added it to the question

Comment: Unfortunately, the example, while being minimal, does not not reproduce the problem, so it's not a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @TheCoder Your code works for me. There's some crucial difference between the bugged code you actually have and the posted code.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I have updated it to include the actual content now, does this help, sorry for the confusion

Comment: It just prints the string with all the `amp`s removed.

Comment: For me the error where random characters are printed to the program still happens

Comment: The current string in the question doesn't even have `amp` in it so what happens if you just do `std::cout << DownloadLink << '\n';`  without the loop?

Comment: The latest example does not contain any `&amp;` which presumably is just some kind of cut and paste error. However if I add some in your code still appears to work. I think the issue here is that the code you have posted is perfectly correct, the bug you have is in some other code. Unfortunately this happens all the time. People are convinced a bug is in one place, post that code, but the code is correct and the bug is somewhere else.

Comment: With the new string, the cleaning of `amp` makes the string into exactly what it looked like in your previous edit of the question. How are you running this program? From an IDE? Does it make a difference if you add a newline at the end of the printing line?

Comment: OK, yet another update to the data, and yet again the posted code is functioning correctly.

Comment: Btw, are you actually running the [mre] in your question on your side and see this issue or do you just _think_ this code should reproduce the issue?

Comment: If I had to guess I would say that the strange output you are seeing is the content you would get if you followed the link you are trying create.

Comment: The error is fixed, it turns out my compiler was corrupt and I reinstalled it and now everything is working correctly, thanks for the help.

Comment: @TheCoder FYI, I would suggest removing the redundant `find()` call and the `try/catch`, you don't need either of them, eg: `string::size_type pos = 0; while ((pos = DownloadLink.find("amp;", pos)) != string::npos) { DownloadLink.replace(pos, 4, ""); }` And then, consider using `erase()` instead of `replace()`, eg: `DownloadLink.erase(pos, 4);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, I would suggest you take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) to correct your use of `using namespace std;` for the reasons listed there.
Secondly, you can replace `replace()` with `erase()` in C++. Trying to replace something with nothing might be improved by just erasing it.
As for the problem, you already stated in the comments that you reinstalled the compiler so that I don't need to address it.

Your code that I modified:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main() {
//You can enter the MrBeast challenge link during initialization
    std::string DownloadLink = "https://rr2---sn-gjo-w43l.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1685464604&amp;ei=vNF1ZPypCYLk8wS04YS4Bw&amp;ip=193.135.13.240&amp;id=o-AOroxIeyjf0SXpp4Jjav3mMxHNrQnAmWFHliIzDxKFK8&amp;itag=22&amp;source=youtube&amp;requiressl=yes&amp;mh=xJ&amp;mm=31%2C29&amp;mn=sn-gjo-w43l%2Csn-ab5sznly&amp;ms=au%2Crdu&amp;mv=m&amp;mvi=2&amp;pl=24&amp;initcwndbps=248750&amp;spc=qEK7B7YCjgMFmSN1lRYNJdgmcwOfjSE&amp;vprv=1&amp;svpuc=1&amp;mime=video%2Fmp4&amp;ratebypass=yes&amp;dur=1535.256&amp;lmt=1685416420579114&amp;mt=1685442532&amp;fvip=1&amp;fexp=24007246%2C24362688%2C51000022&amp;beids=24350017&amp;c=ANDROID&amp;txp=4318224&amp;sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cspc%2Cvprv%2Csvpuc%2Cmime%2Cratebypass%2Cdur%2Clmt&amp;sig=AOq0QJ8wRAIgOFevBFo84_aL0L8hSD1vwztRDGStTF6OaohO4gA8OIUCIE1wN5685dZ7FROQXO9W7BOv4thF8B3KxFE6iefy60xS&amp;lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&amp;lsig=AG3C_xAwRgIhAOO9mtQzsKDrCes2EPmTwOyB8QtGblPFo30I9VrOsSnMAiEAh91ImIfeaugrIfJ4Q0U30viktdo4sWHv0ywQV0kfjt8%3D&amp;title=Ages+1+-+100+Fight+For+$500,000";
    while (true) {
        size_t temp = DownloadLink.find("amp;");//since the link is pretty long, you only have to find it once
        if (temp != std::string::npos) {
            DownloadLink.erase(temp, 4);//you have the position saved in temp
        }
        else { break; }//if there is no more, break
    }
    std::cout << DownloadLink;
    return 0;
}
```